# Rename Excel worksheet without using Excel.Interop

Tags: excel, wcf, reporting-services

Hi is there any way to **rename excel excel worksheet** generated from Reporting Services 2005 which in **.xls** format without using Microsoft excel interop in C#? Is there any open source library that can be used?

**Current Scenario:**

We have 5 worksheets on the excel generated from RS which default name is.

```
Sheet1 --> Sheet 5
```

Where we need to rename ex:

```
Customers , Billing , ....., FrameCount
```

I will rename the work sheet in WCF

**Below are not an option:**

1. Upgrading Reporting Services to 2008
2. Installation of Microsoft Office
3. Free ware only libraries

Thanks

Comment: I'm a little confused what you mean by rename. I assume you're talking more than just changing the name of a file on the file system?

Comment: Oops sorry @lc i will update my post. I mean renaming excel work sheet.

Comment: Gotcha. And I assume it's producing a binary (xls) format, not XML (xlsx), right?

Comment: right @lc .xls (2003 format).

Comment: What's the connection to WCF here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://npoi.codeplex.com/
this is a lib can control excel without install office
or you can find some lib else

Comment: Wow this is great! It works like a charm with just a simple code. @chenZ